# App stays in resuming state when backs from background

Tags: windows-phone-8

I developed a wp8 app recently, but I encounted a weird problem.I locked the screen with the app running in front，but when I unlocked the screen, the resuming tips was showed, and the app stay in resuming state and could not back from the UI.
Does someone encount that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WriteableBitmap can cause the app to be resuming all the time,see this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/5ba20cf3-05c3-421c-9a7f-6c0f24174111/writeablebitmap-freezing-app-when-resuming

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means that you are doing something wrong in terms of resource consumption when resuming the app from dormant state.

Is there any data processing code embedded in the application resume code?

Comment: No, I record the log at every life event function, such as OnNavigatedTo,OnNavigatedFrom，and the log is normal

Comment: Is it happening always or just at random?

Comment: And what's the more weirdly is that the app can response the backkey press and show the messagebox in this resuming state.

Comment: No, I mean the app can responses the interaction when the app stops at the resuming UI which shows "Resuming" text all the time, such as pressing the backkey to show the messagebox.It is seem that the app was recovered with a black panel showing "resuming" text

Comment: Right, but *are* you showing a message box when the app resumes?

Comment: I thing I found the reason, the WriteableBitmap may cause this problem

Comment: To make things easier - edit your original post with a snippet showing **exactly** what you're doing on app resume.

Comment: just like this:
private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
    UIMainPage.Deactivated();

}

public static void Deactivated()
{
    bmp = new WriteableBitmap(myWebBrowser, null);
    bmp.Invalidate();
}